# center align grid without gaps and floating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid set up where the blocks are centre aligned, thus I've done this using `display: inline block` and set `text-align: center` to the container. BUT now the client wants variable heights on the blocks which now leaves big gaps in the grid as they're inline-block. Alternatively I could use `float: left` but this won't work as the blocks need to be centred. I have a codepen setup here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOaeve

I usually use the isotope plugin for grids but there's no layout mode that'll allow for centre aligned blocks so I need a solution that'll allow for all the gaps in the grid to be filled AND for the blocks to be centred. Here's my CSS markup also:

```
.feed-grid {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.feed-grid .grid-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 255px;
}

.feed-grid .grid-block.large {
  height: 522px;
}

.feed-grid .grid-block img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 255px;
}

.feed-grid .grid-block.large img {
  height: 522px;
}
```

Any solutions to this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the images meant to "reflow" changing their position on the grid to close up the gaps?

Comment: @Afrowave yes that's the idea, the gaps need filling...as you achieve using the isotope or masonry plugin for example. Neither of them allow for centred blocks like my demo though

Answer (score 0):

It may solve your problem. I have used `float: left;` in `.child` elements.

```css
.container {background: green; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; padding: 15px;}
.center-element {float: none; background: yellow; overflow: hidden; width: auto; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;}
.child {float: left; padding: 12px 24px; background-color: red;}
.child:not(:first-child) {margin-left: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="center-element">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a vertical middle alignement in the cases you have a smaller image than its "row" ?

Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/Rgeboq/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rowHeight = 0;
  var rowHeights = [];
  var rowCount = 0;
  var offset = $(".grid-block").first().offset().top;

  // Loop throught all images to get their heights.
  $(".grid-block img").each(function(){

    // If on the same row
    if($(this).offset().top == offset){
      // Find the biggest height
      if($(this).height() > rowHeight){
        rowHeight = $(this).height();
        rowHeights[rowCount] = rowHeight;
      }

      // If the row is different.
    }else{
      // Get the new row offset.
      offset = $(this).offset().top;
      rowCount++;

      rowHeight = $(this).height();
      rowHeights.push(rowHeight);
    }

    // Set a custom attribute to apply the right margins.
    $(this).attr("data-row",rowCount);
  });

  //Here you have the array of row heights in console.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(rowHeights));


  // Loop again to apply some margins.
  $(".grid-block img").each(function(){
    var thisRowHeight = rowHeights[parseInt($(this).data("row"))];

    // Apply the margin if this image is smaller than the row height.
    if( $(this).height() < thisRowHeight ){
      var margin = (thisRowHeight - $(this).height() )/2;
      $(this).css({"margin":margin+"px 0"});
    }
  });
});
```

It "measures" the row height to apply a margin to small images... Making them at the middle.

Comment: it's close, the thing is though as I've now got double height images I need to small ones to fill the space around this and leave no gaps – like Masonry or Isotope would do. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: If aspect ratio is not a problem, you could strech them... [**CodePen-v2**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/JJmKWz/)